# Multiplication of columns of a data frame to their respective cell value in a matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix-multiplication

I have to multiply columns of a data frame with an assigned cell value from another matrix. This would, by definition, mean that the number of columns of data frame are equal to number of elements in the matrix.

For eg,

I have a matrix like this

```
         [,1]       [,2]   
[1,] 0.9470883 0.90148918
[2,] 0.6953117 0.69216633
```

and a data frame which looks like this

```
  id val1 val2 val3 val4
1  1    1    1    3    5
2  2    2    1    3    5
3  3    1    1    4    5
4  4    2    1    4    5
5  5    1    1    3    6
6  6    2    1    3    6
7  7    1    1    4    6
8  8    2    1    4    6
```

Each cell of matrix has to be multiplied by respective column of data frame. The matrix can be read in row wise/column wise fashion. Doing this (row wise) the fields would be multiplied as

```
df$val1 <- df$val1*mat[1,1]  #mat[1,1] is 0.9470883
df$val2 <- df$val2*mat[1,2]  #mat[1,2] is 0.90148918
df$val3 <- df$val3*mat[2,1]  #mat[2,1] is 0.6953117
df$val4 <- df$val4*mat[2,2]  #mat[2,2] is 0.69216633
```

So that the output is

```
  id      val1      val2     val3     val4
1  1 0.9470883 0.9014892 2.085935 3.460832
2  2 1.8941766 0.9014892 2.085935 3.460832
3  3 0.9470883 0.9014892 2.781247 3.460832
4  4 1.8941766 0.9014892 2.781247 3.460832
5  5 0.9470883 0.9014892 2.085935 4.152998
6  6 1.8941766 0.9014892 2.085935 4.152998
7  7 0.9470883 0.9014892 2.781247 4.152998
8  8 1.8941766 0.9014892 2.781247 4.152998
```

I want to do this over bigger dimensions of matrix and data frame with something faster than for-loops.

Comment: from the example above: df$val1 is 1 for the first instance. When multiplied by 0.9470083 should be 0.9470083. How are you getting 0.9029538?

Comment: ahh my bad, there was some mistake in copying. Corrected it. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Ok. Are the dimensions of the bigger matrix known? Will the dataframe always only have 4 columns?

Comment: Dimensions of matrix would be 733 x 40 and number of columns will be 733*40 = 29320

Comment: `mapply('*', df, c(mat))` ? Eventually convert to dataframe `as.data.frame(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this (without the column `id`) is:

```
mapply('*', df, c(mat))
```

Eventually convert to dataframe:

```
as.data.frame(mapply('*', df, c(mat)))
```

Example:

```
as.data.frame(mapply('*', cars, c(100, 1000)))
```

**With respect to the column `id` you have a little bit to change:**

```
my.cars <- cbind(id=1:nrow(cars), cars)
cbind(my.cars[1], as.data.frame(mapply('*', my.cars[-1], c(100, 1000))))
```

So in your case:

```
cbind(df[1], as.data.frame(mapply('*', df[-1], c(mat))))
```

Comment: This is what I am going to use, looks like it will work better on large dataset like mine. Thank you

Comment: So eventually you want to accept this answer (or any other) by clicking next to the voting.

Answer (score 2):

```
df <- read.table( header=TRUE,
                  text = "id val1 val2 val3 val4
                    1    1    1    3    5
                    2    2    1    3    5
                    3    1    1    4    5
                    4    2    1    4    5
                    5    1    1    3    6
                    6    2    1    3    6
                    7    1    1    4    6
                    8    2    1    4    6")

M <- matrix( c(0.9470883,0.90148918,0.6953117,0.69216633), byrow=TRUE )

df[,-1] <- t( t(as.matrix(df[,-1])) * rep(t(M),nrow(df)) )
```

.

```
> df
  id      val1      val2     val3     val4
1  1 0.9470883 0.9014892 2.085935 3.460832
2  2 1.8941766 0.9014892 2.085935 3.460832
3  3 0.9470883 0.9014892 2.781247 3.460832
4  4 1.8941766 0.9014892 2.781247 3.460832
5  5 0.9470883 0.9014892 2.085935 4.152998
6  6 1.8941766 0.9014892 2.085935 4.152998
7  7 0.9470883 0.9014892 2.781247 4.152998
8  8 1.8941766 0.9014892 2.781247 4.152998
>
```

Comment: really nice manipulation of data frame and matrix. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We could also use the `sweep`

```
df[-1] <- sweep(df[-1], MARGIN=2, c(t(mat)), '*')
df
#  id      val1      val2     val3     val4
#1  1 0.9470883 0.9014898 2.085935 3.460832
#2  2 1.8941766 0.9014898 2.085935 3.460832
#3  3 0.9470883 0.9014898 2.781247 3.460832
#4  4 1.8941766 0.9014898 2.781247 3.460832
#5  5 0.9470883 0.9014898 2.085935 4.152998
#6  6 1.8941766 0.9014898 2.085935 4.152998
#7  7 0.9470883 0.9014898 2.781247 4.152998
#8  8 1.8941766 0.9014898 2.781247 4.152998
```